# How to solve IndexError: index 151 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 151?

Tags: python, graph

i am having trouble with the following index error, how to solve it?
here is the example code

```
def Myfunc(matrix, pos, neg):

    n1 = 0
    n2 = 0
    n = len(pos) * len(neg)
    for edge in pos:
        try:
            m_s = matrix[edge[0], edge[1]]

            print(edge)

        except KeyError:
            m_s = 0
        # end try
        for edge in neg:
            #print(edge)
            try:
                n_s = matrix[edge[0], edge[1]]
                #print(n_s)
            except KeyError:
                n_s = 0
            # end try

            if m_s > n_s:
                n1 += 1
            elif m_s == n_s:
                n2 += 1

        value=(n1 + (0.5* n2)) / n
    return value
```

neg=
[  1  59]
[  1  61]
...
[140 148]
[140 149]
[148 149]]

pos=[[  2   3][  2   4] [  2  18] [  2  19] [  2  20][  2  28]

martix

[image]

error

> IndexError: index 151 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 151

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: In python indexing starts from `0`. So, a list with 151 elements (size = 151) will contain elements with indices 0...150.

Comment: So what should I do @RomanZhuravlev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python indexing starts from 0. So, a list with 151 elements (size = 151) will contain elements with indices 0...150.

You have two options here:

1. Adjust your list of "edges pairs" so it contains only allowable indices (this depends on how do you generate this list)
2. Or just make use `matrix[edge[0] - 1, edge[1] - 1]` if you sure that the error is the same for all your indices

Anyway, keep in mind the right indexing and everything will be alright ;)

Comment: How? can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: I don't know how did you obtain these lists. So or manually, or adjust the method that generates these lists

Comment: this list contain edges pairs of the graph

Comment: Ok, apparently somewhere in this list there is a pair dor which `edge[1] = 151`. So when you are trying to access `matrix[edge[0], edge[1]]` you get an error because the maximum allowable index for this matrix is 150. You have two options here: or adjust your list of "edges pairs" so it contains only allowable indices (this depends on how you generate this list); or just make `matrix[edge[0] - 1, edge[1] - 1]` if you sure that the error is the same for all your indices.